# Anyone experience vscode very slow after update to 1.30?

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

What settings to disable to make it fast again?

I'm using VSCode for flutter development. Now very slow when starting the app and during hot reload. Now almost impossible to perform hot reload. I must stop it, do changes then start rather than waiting on hot reload process.
Before update, it was fast but sometimes crash.

I only use Dart 2.21.1 and Flutter 2.21.1 extension. And running on Windows 10.

[image: Task Manager]

=======================================================================

The issue seems gone away.

Now I'm using VS Code 1.31.1

> flutter --version

```
Flutter 1.1.8 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 985ccb6d14 (8 weeks ago) • 2019-01-08 13:45:55 -0800
Engine • revision 7112b72cc2
Tools • Dart 2.1.1 (build 2.1.1-dev.0.1 ec86471ccc)
```

And Dart/Flutter extension is 2.24.0

Comment: Could be https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28383#issuecomment-447987219

Comment: Yes it is high CPU usage

Comment: @rxlky Can you confirm which version of Flutter you have (it's shown in the lower right status bar when you have a Flutter project and a .dart file open), an which process is using up the CPU (if possibly, get the command line).

Comment: @DannyTuppeny it's latest flutter 1.0.0

Comment: @rxlky and which process is consuming all the CPU?

Comment: @DannyTuppeny what process? I'll update my question hopefully it's correct what you mean.

Comment: @rxlky Thanks - the screenshot shows the CPU is in the VS Code process (as opposed to say, the Dart analyzer). Could you run `code --status` when this is happening - this will show a breakdown of the CPU for Code vs extension host. There's some info on this at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Performance-Issues

Comment: For now it's not happening again maybe flutter clean solves it. But when it happens again I'll update it.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny I've updated screenshot of code --status

Comment: @rxlky Thanks - would you mind opening an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code then capturing a log (see https://dartcode.org/docs/logging/#capture-logs-command) and emailing it to logs @ dartcode .org including the GH issue number for me to take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems gone away.

Now I'm using VS Code 1.31.1

> flutter --version

```
Flutter 1.1.8 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 985ccb6d14 (8 weeks ago) • 2019-01-08 13:45:55 -0800
Engine • revision 7112b72cc2
Tools • Dart 2.1.1 (build 2.1.1-dev.0.1 ec86471ccc)
```

And Dart/Flutter extension is 2.24.0

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes possible, thanks... I will give it a try. Hopefully it is safe to delete this folder

Comment: It's safe to delete, but it will be created again quickly. It might grow less if you don't open Dart/flutter projects anymore you opened before.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer no it doesn't help even it generated less files but still slow. until I run flutter clean.

Answer (score 1):

In your folder, run

```
flutter clean
```

this will delete all flutter dependencies and then re-create the project again by using

```
flutter create YourProjectName
```

this will create all the flutter dependencies again in your current project, you will not loose your files